# Fantasy movie with magical cliffs that crush a ship

Tags: story-identification

In the early 2000s, I watched a live-action English-language fantasy movie on New Zealand television but I only remember one thing about it.

Near the end, the characters were on a ship and they had to sail through an inlet between two cliffs. Problem was, the cliffs were magical and the gap was closing. I remember that they actually didn't make it in time and the ship got crushed. What was this movie?

Comment: Was this live action or cartoon? If you remember can you [edit] your question to specify and add in anything else you can think of. Remember every little thing can help others identify this for you!

Comment: It sounds like the story of Jason and the argonauts.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bz9OcRHumAg

Comment: Are you certain they weren't being chased and it was their pursuers who got crushed?

Comment: That clip is similar, but that's not it. I distinctly remember the ship being destroyed by the gap closing completely, but in that clip, the ship survives and passes through to the other side. Also, I don't remember any big beings in the inlet and I think I would have remembered something like that.

Comment: "Are you certain they weren't being chased and it was their pursuers who got crushed?" - I only remember one ship being involved but if you show me a clip of the second ship that you mention, I can tell you if it's familiar.

Comment: The cliffs could possibly be Scylla and Charybdis with [Charybdis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charybdis) being the one swallowing ships. How did the movie look? Was there a lot of CGI, was it an older Sword and Sandal film?

Answer (score 19):

Almost certainly [***Jason and the Argonauts***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057197/) (1963)

I don't have a clip but the [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_and_the_Argonauts_(1963_film)) synosis confirms a ship was crushed.

> The Argonauts next meet Phineus, who has been blinded and is tormented by harpies for misusing Zeus's gift of prophesy. After the Argonauts capture and cage the harpies, Phineus tells them how to reach Colchis, by sailing between the **Clashing Rocks**. He also gives Jason an amulet of the sea god Triton.
>
> **The Argonauts see another ship trying to pass through the Clashing Rocks the other way, only to be crushed and sunk when the Clashing Rocks smash together.**
>
> The Argonauts rescue a survivor, Medea, high priestess of Colchis. When the Argo tries to row through, the ship appears destined for destruction as well. In despair, Jason throws Phineus's amulet into the water, whereupon Triton rises up out of the water and holds the rocks apart so the Argo can pass.

---

More recently, there was a TV miniseries [***Jason and the Argonauts***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0217579/) (2000) which featured a similar scene.

The ship crushing scene for the this version is shown very briefly in [this trailer at around 0:30.](https://youtu.be/M_VAQW-tDCg?t=29)

Comment: Sigh.  Right story, obviously, but the TV and movie folks apparently decided their audience couldn't deal with Scylla and Charybdis...

Comment: The Clashing Rocks are different from Scylla and Charybdis, the latter being more generally associated with Odysseus. The Symplegades (the Greek name for the Clashing Rocks) are definitely part of the Jason myth

Comment: After looking into these more, it was probably the 2000 version. It generally appears more familiar than the 1963 version. The movie I remember didn't have Triton pushing apart the cliffs or any skeleton warriors, which fits the 2000 version better. Also, I distinctly remember the ship scene being quite close to the ending. That doesn't actually fit either version, but since the 2000 version was in two parts, it was probably close to the end of the first part.